Excel process ratcheting up RAM use and becoming background process after closing
On two computers in my office, but none of the others, RAM usage continuously increases when working in certain workbooks in Excel. It appears that it happens with any workbook that has VBA macros, and when working in those workbooks, the Excel process also does not close after closing the Excel window. It remains open as a background process, and the RAM consumption decreases just slightly.
On all the other computers I tested this on, the RAM usage fluctuates up and down, but is generally reasonably low, and does not exhibit the behavior of locking into a level that it never comes back below.
In searching the web, I found quite a few links that mentioned the splwow64.exe issue, but I have tried all the solutions mentioned in those links and they have not worked (removing printers, disabling print spooler). Indeed, on these systems, the wait chain indicates that splwow64.exe is the process Excel is waiting for to be able to close, but ending splwow64.exe does not automatically end the excel process as other threads indicate it should, and nothing gets better until excel is manually killed in Task Manager.
I'm lucky to have an office full of computers that I can test on, so what I've done so far is run a few different workbooks on each of the different computers and watched the RAM usage in Task Manager. The most effective way to see the difference was to use an older workbook in which I had written a farily inefficient VBA macro. That allowed me to quickly determine which computers had the ratcheting issue. It was only the two I've mentioned.
The two computers in question are both on Windows 11. They are different builds from each other, but one of them is the same build as many of the other computers I tested on.
One is somewhat faster than the other, but in running the test on other computers, I also used some considerably slower systems, and they did not have the issue.
Both "bad" computers are SSD/mSata only systems (no HDD), as are many of the other computers I tested on. One of the computers has an AMD processor. The other is an Intel. All the others I tested on are Intel.
I tested on computers with RAM ranging from 8GB to 32GB. The "bad" computers are 16GB and 32GB.
The Office version and build on the two computers is also the same as many of the other computers I tested on.
The problem is definitely specific to these two computers, as I tested with identical files across all the different computers. I'm not sure where else to go from here, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know any other information I can share that would be helpful as well.
Thanks!

What does Event Viewer have to say?

I haven't looked there, but I don't really know what I'd be looking for anyway. Is there a specific item that I should be paying attention to in Event Viewer to better understand the problem?

I generally start looking for entries around the time of the issue. I'll also look for any errors or warnings, and for any log entries regarding the process having issues. These three different searches are usually sufficient, unless I have something more specific to look for.

I just watched event viewer while running the process on one of the computers. Nothing stood out to me as a major error or anything like that. I didn't see any indication that the process reported any issues. Again though, I may not be looking in the right place.

Update: I ran Process Explorer on both computers to try to figure out more about what was going on. I realized that when running Process Explorer normally, which is the 64-bit version, Excel did not even appear in the process list, and could not be found using the target tool. This led me to uninstall Office and reinstall it, ensuring that I chose the 64 bit installer. On one computer this appears to have worked, and now Excel shows up in the 64-bit version of Process Explorer.

On the other computer, the same fix worked immediately after the reinstall, but it has since reverted back to running poorly. I will investigate further, but also appreciate any input anyone can offer to help more.

In my enterprise environment we've found some surprising issues with 64bit Office versions. Not bugs, but incompatibilities that we didn't expect, and the word from MS was that, in general, we should be using the 32bit Office versions except for cases where a unique workload required the 64bit version. Not super relevant to your main issue, but a factor you may need to at least be aware of going forward. I've never had problems with ProcExp not being able to see processes in a different bit-ness, so I'd look into what's going on there a bit more.
